# ZF2 Model Mapper

Tags: php, zend-framework

In the ZF2 model mapper, mappings are quite often duplicated in the original mapping class & other mapping classes.

I am using a static mapping methods (`mapToInternal`, `mapToExternal`) to remove this duplication.  Could this be done any better?

```
<?php

//...

/**
 * Class ItemTable
 *
 * @package Job\Model\Mapper\Item
 */
class ItemTable extends Table implements ItemInterface
{

/**
 * @param \ArrayObject $external
 * @return ItemEntity
 */
static public function mapToInternal(\ArrayObject $external)
{
    $item = new ItemEntity();
    empty($external->id) ? : $item->setId($external->id);
    empty($external->account_id) ? : $item->setAccountId($external->account_id);
    empty($external->title) ? : $item->setTitle($external->title);
    empty($external->description) ? : $item->setDescription($external->description);
    empty($external->created_on) ? : $item->setCreatedOn($external->created_on);
    empty($external->updated_on) ? : $item->setUpdatedOn($external->updated_on);

    return $item;
}

/**
 * @param ItemEntity $item
 * @return array
 */
static public function mapToExternal(ItemEntity $item)
{
    $data = array(
        'id'          => $item->getId(),
        // @todo complete once login is done
        'account_id'  => 1, //$item->getAccountId(),
        'title'       => $item->getTitle(),
        'description' => $item->getDescription(),
        'updated_on'  => $item->getUpdatedOn(),
        'created_on'  => $item->getCreatedOn(),
    );

    return $data;
}

/**
 * return array
 */
public function findAll()
{
    $response = $this->getDao()->findAll();

    $items = array();
    foreach ($response as $item) {
        $itemEntity = self::mapToInternal($item);
        $statisticEntity = ItemStatisticTable::mapToInternal($item);
        $itemEntity->setStatistic($statisticEntity);

        $items[] = $itemEntity;
    }

    return $items;
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Two minor notes:

1. This function uses only data of `ItemEntity`:

   > ```
   > static public function mapToExternal(ItemEntity $item)
   > {
   >     $data = array(
   >         'id'          => $item->getId(),
   >         // @todo complete once login is done
   >         'account_id'  => 1, //$item->getAccountId(),
   >         'title'       => $item->getTitle(),
   >         'description' => $item->getDescription(),
   >         'updated_on'  => $item->getUpdatedOn(),
   >         'created_on'  => $item->getCreatedOn(),
   >     );
   >
   >     return $data;
   > }
   > ```

   I would consider putting this function into the `ItemEntity` class. It seems [data envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy).
2. It's confusing here that `$items` does not contain any `$item`:

   > ```
   > $items = array();
   > foreach ($response as $item) {
   >     $itemEntity = self::mapToInternal($item);
   >     $statisticEntity = ItemStatisticTable::mapToInternal($item);
   >     $itemEntity->setStatistic($statisticEntity);
   >
   >     $items[] = $itemEntity;
   > }
   >
   > return $items;
   > ```

   I'd rename it to `$result` to describe its purpose.